# Accessing multiple service instances through a single application via OAuth for REST

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want to create an application in serviceNow(like Facebook) which through OAuth will be able to call the REST APIs for different instances.

Suppose, I create an app in instance A of servicenow, now through proper OAuth and permission mechanism, I want to access REST APIs of other instances.

Till now, I am able to create an app and have it registered in application registry, and I am also able to verify Oauth (generate tokens) for that instance; but now I want to do it for other instances without creating a new application each time. When I try to do it, I am getting this error:

> unauthorized_client: The client credentials provided (those of the
>   service you are using) are either not valid or not trusted

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you are attempting to do this when you are receiving the error that you posted?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.. I have same issue and switched to use basic auth instead of oauth

Answer (score 2):

In your application on Instance A,
you need to save OAUTH credentials for each of the instances you're connecting to.
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-servicenow-platform/page/product/meeting-extensibility/task/create-app-registry-meeting-extensibility.html

In your app depending on which instance you are connecting to you need to use the correct credential for that instance.

It is **not** possible to reuse the same OAUTH tokens for multiple instances, as it is possible to reuse the same username:password combo with basic auth.

However you can create a oauth_entity_profile for each connection.
Then when doing you're request loop over the list of instances, before sending the request inject the correct authentication.
https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/rome/server/sn_ws-namespace/c_RESTMessageV2API#r_RMV2-setAuthenticationProfile_S_S

While also calling the correct url for the given instance using:
https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/rome/server/sn_ws-namespace/c_RESTMessageV2API#r_RESTMessageV2_setEndpoint_String_endpoint

```js
var instances = [{name: 'instance_x', oauth_id: '2394829384..'}, {name: 'instance_y', oauth_id: '2394829384..'};
for (var i = 0; i < instances.length; i++){
    var inst = instances[i];
    var sm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2("<REST_message_record>", "get");  

       //set auth profile to an OAuth 2.0 profile record.
    sm.setAuthenticationProfile('oauth2', inst.oauth_id); 
    sm.setEndpoint("http://web.service.endpoint");


       //In milliseconds. Wait at most 10 seconds for response from http request.
    sm.setHttpTimeout(10000); 
       //Might throw exception if http connection timed out or some issue 
       //with sending request itself because of encryption/decryption of password.
    var response = sm.execute();
    // handle your reponse  
}
```

Where instances.oauth_id are the id's of records in the oauth_entity_profile table.
Which need to be active and have their tokens for it all to work.